# How to handle catch block with functions?

Tags: java, error-handling, try-catch

I'm curious to know, Suppose i've a function says `myFunction()`. Take a look into this sample:

```
public void myFunction() {
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 15; i++) {
            System.out.println("Counting: " + i);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Now if any kind of error is caught inside this function, I want to handle this error like this would start again that `myFunction()`. How to do that?

I mean, how to include that function inside `catch(Exception e)` so that it could start again that function? Is it possible?

*Help would be appreciated!*

Comment: You can  add `myFunction()` inside catch statement

Comment: But it is inside that function.. lol . Would it work?

Comment: You should only do this if there is a real chance that retrying the same thing again succeeds the second time around. And there should be a maxRetry, otherwise it might loop forever.

Comment: Why you will do so. If you get an exception every time, your code never ends.

Comment: have you heard about the term called recursion. i guess that is what you are talking about and what specific requirement do you have for which you need to do this.

Comment: if it is error in your function, then you will get exception every time.

Comment: @IswantoSan And it seems extreme to use `recursion` to handle your exceptions and retries, when an iterative solution is trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void myFunction() {
    boolean successful = false;
    int retryCount = 0;
    while(retryCount < 5 && !successful) {
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 15; i++) {
                System.out.println("Counting: " + i);
            }
            successful = true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            successful = false;
            retryCount++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @thilo adding a retry should be simple, sec

Comment: Hey!! Thanks.. I want to ask you one thing.. Are you sure it should be `false` inside `boolean successful = false;` ? Why don't you use `true` here?

Comment: Of course, a much smarter way of doing this would include some kind of task scheduler which would increase the delay time between retries, exponentially for example. But this answers the basic question, which is to put it in a loop. If the last line of the `try` block is `successful = true`, then that will execute only if the statement ran successfully (no exception was thrown), otherwise you'll stay in the loop.

Comment: Depends on the task if a delay would help, or if some parameters should be tweaked (or if a retry is completely pointless).

Comment: @Thilo true, I figured you are trying to talk to a server or something, then retrying immediately is usually a bad choice.

Comment: Thanks... :) I would accept your answer after `5 minutes`

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem about Catch or Propagate Exceptions, in http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-exception-handling/basic-try-catch-finally.html#catch-or-propagating-exceptions . I also recommend you to write your custom exception handling the problem and read that tutorial. Here are the things that you must follow

> It depends on the situation. In many applications you can't really do
>   much about the exception but tell the user that the requested action
>   failed. In these applications you can usually catch all or most
>   exceptions centrally in one of the first methods in the call stack.
>   You may still have to deal with the exception while propagating it
>   though (using finally clauses). For instance, if an error occurs in
>   the database connection in a web application, you may still have to
>   close the database connection in a finally clause, even if you can't
>   do anything else than tell the user that the action failed. How you
>   end up handling exceptions also depends on whether you choose checked
>   or unchecked exceptions for your application. There is more on that in
>   other texts in the error handling trail.

I recommend you, for your propossits that you propagate your exception this way:

public void myFunction() thows MyException{

```
try{

for(int i=0; i<=15;i++){
    System.out.println("Counting: "+i);     
    }

}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    Thows new MyException()
}

}

public class MyException extends Exception {
    public MyException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

Then you can execute your function in a context that you can restart if the problem is why you want to reestart

```
 begin for example a while lool

try {
   Function();
}catch MyException {
   start again
}
```